# Inserting a DBNull value into a database

Tags: c#, database, null

I have code which works pretty well. I just need some of your opinions on how to write it better with fewer line of code. I want to use a ternary operator but I couldn't make it work so I did an `if else` instead.

Basically, I want to insert a price on my database. The price column is a nullable decimal. Even in my C# code, it's a nullable decimal as well.

```
if (items.Price == null)
{
    SqlParameter[] p =
    {
        new SqlParameter("@purchaseorder", items.PurchaseOrderItems),
        new SqlParameter("@modelnumber", items.ModelNumber), 
        new SqlParameter("@quantity", items.Quantity),
        new SqlParameter("@Price",  DBNull.Value),
        new SqlParameter("@Description", items.Description),
        new SqlParameter("@OrderNumber", items.OrderNumber),
        new SqlParameter("@Unit", items.Unit)
    };

    i = Dal.ExecuteNonQuery(sql,p);
}
else
{
    SqlParameter[] p =
    {
        new SqlParameter("@purchaseorder", items.PurchaseOrderItems),
        new SqlParameter("@modelnumber", items.ModelNumber), 
        new SqlParameter("@quantity", items.Quantity),
        new SqlParameter("@Price",  items.Price),
        new SqlParameter("@Description", items.Description),
        new SqlParameter("@OrderNumber", items.OrderNumber),
        new SqlParameter("@Unit", items.Unit)
    };

    i = Dal.ExecuteNonQuery(sql,p);
}
return i;
```

Can this be written without the `else` block?

Comment: Why not make life easier and use an ORM? ["if you’re writing ADO.Net code by hand, you’re stealing from your employer or client."](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/07/24/dont-write-your-own-orm/)

Comment: @BCdotWEB As a few coders out there commented on that post, if people followed that advice we wouldn't have all of those pretty ORMs out there. Sometimes, doing it the old, artisanal way is the best way to learn - we learn about the difficulties and discover what problems we need to solve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you have to do is to use the [`?:` *(ternary operator)*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
new SqlParameter("@Price", items.Price == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)items.Price)
```

Alternatively you could write an extension for it:

```
public static object PriceOrDefault(this ItemsType items)
{
    return items.Price == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)items.Price;
}
```

and use it instead:

```
new SqlParameter("@Price", items.PriceOrDefault())
```

---

As it turns out the `Price` is a `decimal?` so you may consider using the `HasValue` property and swap the values:

```
items.Price.HasValue ? (object)items.Price : DBNull.Value;
```

*I find this looks better then the null-check.*

Comment: Sorry, but i got a squiggly line underneath.
https://s15.postimg.org/xmy26aduz/werw.png

Comment: @DikongPrigm Just cust it to `object`. I edited the examples. `SqlParameter` excpects it anyway.

Comment: That works.. Thank.  I will wrap this to extension method. Thank you

Comment: If you go with the helper method, I'd rather go with the more general `object NulltoDBNull(object o) { return o != null ? o : DBNull.Value; }`.

Answer (score 11):

The most terse and declarative way to write this is to use C#'s `??` operator. Your line becomes:

```
new SqlParameter("@Price",  (object)items.Price ?? DbNull.Value),
```

The expression here will either return the non-null value of the left operand (`items.Price`), or return the operand to the right instead.

If you hadn't guessed, the `??` operator is basically syntactic sugar for if `operl  != null ? operl : operr`.

Comment: nice, I actually know this one too but didn't think it would work like this with a nullable :-]

Comment: Using null coalescing is definitely the cleanest option.

Answer (score 5):

This is down to personal taste, but if you do go down the extension method route [suggested by t3chb0t](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/143760/4203), I'd consider making it generic so that you can reuse it for any future `Nullable` types you might use and you don't end up with a bunch of very similar looking functions for different fields.  Something like this:

```
public static object DbValueOrNull<T>(this T? value) where T : struct
{
    return value.HasValue ? (object)value.Value : DBNull.Value;
}
```

Would allow:

```
new SqlParameter("@Price", items.Price.DbValueOrNull())
new SqlParameter("@SomeOtherNullableVar", items.SomeOtherNullableVar.DbValueOrNull())
```

etc.

Comment: wow, I believe I've never come up with the idea to use the _nullable_ `?` on a `T` + `struct` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the [System.Data.SqlTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace - particularly [SqlDecimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldecimal(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Building on some of the other answers, you can use `SqlDecimal` and the `??` operator as follows:

```
new SqlParameter("@Price",  items.Price ?? SqlDecimal.Null),
```